# Formatting the number in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I want to format a numeric value to two decimal points (it is an integer variable)
I am using following expression (as used to use in vb6) but it is not working.  Please advise how to fix it.

```
="Total Drawings Rs. " & format(Parameters!TotalDrawings.Value,"@@@@@@@@@@@.00")"
```

Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [.net format string,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28VS.95%29.aspx) not VB6/VBA

```
= "Total Drawings Rs. " + Format(CDbl(Parameters!TotalDrawings.Value), "##########0.00")
```

Edit: fixed concat + trailing " + CDbl

Comment: No sir ! It is printing ###########0.00 instead of my formatted value.

Comment: @user415037: hopefully fixed. Did your code show @@@@@@@@@@@.00 ?

Comment: Yes, I also tried =format(Parameter!TotalDrawings.value,"N") and it printed N instead of my value in N format.